# Laravel 4 using jitimage: it works on locally but gives error on testing server

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I'm using the jitimage package to re-size and display images. Everything works fine on my local machine but it gives an error on my testing server.

You can see the error here: http://dev.gradimsam.si/images/4/208/150/upload/articles/kritina1.jpg

The error is:

> preg_match(): Compilation failed: nothing to repeat at offset 185

Can someone please help me understand this error?

Comment: Post the code/errors here.

Comment: I can see the error alright, `You don't have permission to access /images/4/208/150/upload/articles/kritina1.jpg on this server.` - **"Double Jeopardy"**. Gawd, I love that TV show, twice a day!

Comment: The link should work now and you will see the error I was talking about. I forgot to allow access, sorry.

Comment: No problemo. Well this one's "out of my league", *sorry*. Hope you get the help needed. Cheers

Comment: Show us what `$compiledRoute->getRegex()` returns just before that error...

Comment: Sorry I'm new to Laravel...how can I show you that?

Comment: Erm, nothing to do with Laravel, bare php... just add a `var_dump(compiledRoute->getRegex())` before that `preg_match` call.

Comment: I think I can't do that, it is in the bootstrap/compiled.php file which is generated by the framework.

Comment: Hogwash. It's not immutable, just edit it, or edit the original class file & regenerate it. First of all BTW , note you need PHP version >= 5.3.7, 5.3.6 or lower: a no go.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

author of jitimage here.

This issues was caused by an positive lookahead that failed to compile in earlier php5.4 versions, and has been fixed now (v0.1.1).

For reference https://github.com/iwyg/jitimage/issues/5

Cheers, Thomas

Answer (score 0):

You have to rebuild your php with the newest PCRE library

Comment: Is there a simple way of doing that without losing my configuration?